# How to debug COM exceptions, caused by Excel Interop, in C# program?

Tags: c#, excel, debugging, office-interop

I'm working on a C# application, trying to use Excel features. In order to do that, I'm working with Interop as a library. I have an exception in following line of source code:

```
Range rng_Destination = 
  xlApp.get_Range(xlWrkSht.Cells[2,1], 
                  xlWrkSht.Cells[xlWrkSht.Cells[1,1].CurrentArray.Rows.Count+1,
                                    dt_main.Columns.Count]);
```

In order to investigate this, I've tried to add `xlWrkSht.Cells[2,1]` to Visual Studio's Watch window, but this just shows `{System.__ComObject}`, which is not very useful.

So, I tried another approach, using this kind of source code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("xlWrkSht.Cells[2 ,1]: [%s]", 
                                   xlWrkSht.Cells[2, 1]);
```

This, however, causes following `Exception`:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Cannot dynamically invoke method 'WriteLine' because it has 
        a Conditional attribute
Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
StackTrace:<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

So my question is very simple: how can I debug Interop related objects, like the mentioned `xlWrkSht.Cells[2, 1]`?

For your information: I already tried unchecking "Just my code" but this did not help until now (I found this somewhere on the internet, I have no idea what it does):

[image: Just my code screenshot]

I've been looking for other resources about `Interop` debugging, but the information was far too general to be useful for my specific case.
I've also seen some posts on the internet, informing about the event viewer but there, I just have some "Information" and at most some "Warning" messages, no "Error" ones (I've been looking in "Windows Logs, Application/Security and System".

**Edit after some more investigation**
Meanwhile I've seen that I can find the value of that cell, using:

```
xlWrkSht.Cells[2, 1]
=> Dynamic View
  FormulaLocal
```

That last attribute contains the value.

However, the following issue is that I'll need to get the Excel array this cell belongs to:

```
xlWrkSht.Cells[2, 1].CurrentArray.
```

This one seems not to be accessible, even not using "Dynamic view". Any ideas?

Comment: Solve the first problem by assigning the Cells[] reference to a variable of type Range so the dynamic binder is not needed anymore.  Solve the second problem by temporarily setting the "Embed Interop Types" property of the assembly reference to False.

Comment: If I set "Embed Interop Types" to `false` I can't use `.CurrentArray` anymore.

Comment: You may want to download/install the Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity tool-it will allow you to see how a .xlsx file is structured: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

Comment: @HansPassant: pardon my ignorance, but I have the impression that, when I type something like `xlWrkSht[1,1]` or even `xlWrkSht.Cells[1,1].FormulaLocal` (simple attributes or properties), Visual Studio asks the connected Excel instance to calculate this while I would expect that information already being loaded into memory. Does this mean that Interop is the wrong package for working with Excel and in that case, which package is better suited for my needs?